# Scale more than one dynamically loaded SVG images in a single parent container -Angular7

Tags: svg, dynamic, angular7, scaling

I have a requirement  where I need to add on SVG images one after another(stack vertically) and it should scale accordingly without any scrollbar for parent container in Angular7. The images are added dynamically. My problem is I don't know how to scale these images with respect to the parent container (There is only one single parent container for all the SVG's) and there should not be any scrollbar to view the svgs. The SVG images should scale accordingly.

My HTMl is like this:

```
<div id="stackedSVGParentContainer">
    <svg  width="16" height="4.5" viewBox="0 0 16 5" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <path d="M0.738516 4.5L2.33852 0.5H13.6615L15.2615 4.5H2.33852Z" fill="#E0E0E0" stroke="#212121"/>
         <line x1="1" y1="1.75" x2="15" y2="1.75" stroke="#262121" stroke-width="0.5"/>
         <line x1="2" y1="3.25" x2="14" y2="3.25" stroke="#262121" stroke-width="0.5"/>
    </svg>
    <svg width="16" height="135" viewBox="0 0 16 150" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
         <rect _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c326="" x="2.5" y="25.5" width="11" height="99" fill="#E0E0E0" stroke="#262121"></rect>
    </svg>
    <svg width="16" height="135" viewBox="0 0 16 150" fill="none" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
           <rect _ngcontent-ng-cli-universal-c326="" x="2.5" y="25.5" width="11" height="99" fill="#E0E0E0" stroke="#212621"></rect>
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: @aminmohammadi how did you find the code to add in your suggested edit?

Comment: @RobertoCaboni it was right there in the question plain text, but user forgot to put it in code section identifiers and as it was html so nothing was rendered, I just put code identifiers around existing plain texts.